# Pushshift Telegram dataset (https://zenodo.org/record/3607497): chat messages vs. channel messages?

Tags: telegram, telethon

I am using the Pushshift Telegram dataset (link in title) and I am having a hard time assessing what the actual contents of the dataset are. The dataset contains messages posted to Telegram channels, but the paper also suggests that some of these channels have an associated 'chat'. I am only interested in public broadcasting channels, that is, channels in which the owner of a channel posts messages, but which cannot be interacted with by other users. When I link messages to channels based on the IDs in the dataset, I am not sure how I can distinguish between messages that are part of the actual broadcasting channels, or messages that are associated with the 'chat' of that channel. Perhaps something has changed to Telegram in the meantime, but I was under the impression that there is no 'chat' of any sort associated with broadcasting channels.

My question is thus: which metadata field in the output of the Telethon API (used to collect the pushshift data) allows me to distinguish between a message posted in a broadcast channel, and a message posted in the 'chat' associated with the channel?